# python: Trying to loop to a raw_input after an else statement

Tags: python

Just started teaching myself python today. But cant figure out how to use an else statement to loop back to a previous raw_input

```
print "Please enter your name below so I may know what to call you."
time.sleep(3)
name = raw_input("Name:")
time.sleep(1)
print "Your name is %s, correct?" % (name)
time.sleep(2)
verify = raw_input()
  if verify = "yes":
    print "Hello %s, it is very nice to meet you." % (name)

  else:
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of Python. First of all `verify = "yes"` is an assignment. What you need is `if verify == "yes":` Now, your `else` would be executed when verify is not equal to `yes`

Comment: You have a long and winding road to go. For starters, read about `for` and `while` loops.

Comment: Use '==' instead of '=' in if loop